# Show that linearized gravity is a Lorentz-invariant theory of tensor field on flat spacetime

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, tensor-calculus, lorentz-symmetry

For linearized gravity $G_{\mu\nu} = 8 \pi G T_{\mu\nu} $, for 
$$
G_{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \partial_\sigma \partial_\nu {h^\sigma}_\mu + \partial_\sigma \partial_\mu {h^\sigma}_\nu -\partial_\mu \partial_\nu h - \square h_{\mu\nu} - \eta_{\mu \nu} \partial_\rho \partial_\lambda h^{\rho \lambda} + \eta_{\mu \nu} \square h \right]
$$
We let $T_{\mu \nu}$ be describing dust. By deriving the transformation properties of $h_{\mu \nu}$, we want to show that this describes a Lorentz-invariant theory of a symmetric rank-2 tensor field (h) on flat spacetime.

**My attempt:**
I thought the only straight forward way to do this was by showing that the Lagrangian density of the theory is lorentz invariant. According to Carroll the Lagrangian density is
$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} \left[ (\partial_\mu {h^{\mu \nu }} )(\partial_\nu h) - (\partial_\mu {h^{\rho \sigma}} )(\partial_\rho {h^{\mu }}_{ \sigma} ) + \frac{1}{2}  \eta^{\mu \nu} (\partial_\mu {h^{\rho \sigma }} )(\partial_\nu {h}_{\rho \sigma } ) - \frac{1}{2} \eta^{\mu \nu}(\partial_\mu h )(\partial_\nu h ) \right]
$$
However, every attempt I made failed which makes me wonder if I didn't understand the question properly or if I am plain stupid. Consider the last term for instance:
$$
 \eta^{\mu \nu}(\partial_\mu h )(\partial_\nu h )
 = (\partial_\mu h )(\partial^\mu h )
$$
We must have $(\partial_\mu h )(\partial^\mu h ) \to (\partial_\mu h )(\partial^\mu h )$, otherwise $\mathcal{L}$ is not lorentz invariant. However, when I try to Lorentz transform one of the factors:
$$
\partial_\mu h  \to \eta^{\rho \sigma} {\Lambda_\mu}^\nu {\Lambda^\alpha}_\rho {\Lambda^\beta}_\sigma \partial_\nu h_{\alpha \beta},
$$
which gets me nowhere. I get a similar mess for all the other terms. Any hints to help me make some progress or spotting mistakes would be appreciated.

Comment: Lagrangians need not to be invariant!!! The action is invariant. This means that your Lagrangian can change by a total derivative. Moreover, you know what is $\eta^{\rho \sigma} \Lambda^{\alpha}_{\vphantom{\alpha} \rho} \Lambda^{\beta}_{\vphantom{\beta} \sigma}$, don't you?

Comment: Aha! Any suggestions how I would do it differently?

Comment: Your approach is fine. Usually that is why people deal with index notation. It makes the transformation properties manifest. Play a bit with $\partial_{\mu} h$ like you are doing and any questions please do come back.

Comment: I know what $\eta^{\rho \sigma} {\Lambda_\rho}^\alpha{\Lambda_\sigma}^\beta$ is. But not what $\eta^{\rho \sigma} {\Lambda^\alpha}_\rho{\Lambda^\beta}_\sigma$ is, which is what I have in my expression.

Comment: You can figure it out by knowing that $x^{\mu} x_{\mu}$ is a scalar, that is, it doesn't change when Lorentz rotated.

Comment: Is this correct?
$$x_\sigma x_\rho {\Lambda^\rho}_\mu \eta^{\mu \nu}{\Lambda^\sigma}_\nu = x_\sigma x_\rho {(\Lambda^T)_\mu}^\rho \eta^{\mu \nu}{(\Lambda^T)_\nu}^\sigma = x^\mu x_\mu = x'^\mu x'_\mu = x_\rho x_\sigma{\Lambda_\mu}^\rho \eta^{\mu\nu} {\Lambda_\nu}^\sigma $$